# Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've read all other posts before posting but even when 'fixing'
it's still not working and keeps giving me that error.
I guess that from newer versions of Chrome now It's only possible to include local extensions?
My manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; 
object-src 'self'",
"name": "MyExtensionPrice",
"description": "MyExtension",
"version": "1.0",


"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
 "activeTab"
 ]

}
```

Comment: I see the error in the console,
I use an body onload too

Comment: So far it looks like a duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)